# Object doesn't support this property or method - How can I put other operations in this loop?

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I'm trying to introduce more operations/assign values to variables and cells in a For loop however I am getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error because of the line **.Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value = YesterdaysOpen**.

I know I need to qualify it but i thought that was done at the start of the With statement. Obviously given the error it was not, so i tried adding .Range in front, also adding the full address

`Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value`

but that generates the same error. I feel like I am missing something in the structure of the loop/syntax but have not located a comparable example i understand either on here or via google (so i'm posting the question).

```
`With Worksheets("Data processing")
ClosingPrice200Array = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 5), .Cells(LastRow, 5)).Value 'pass the first range to the ClosingPrice200Array

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row ' this assigns the row number of the last used row in column 4 to the variable "LastRow"

    LastRowOffset = (LastRow - FirstRow + 1) - MovingAverageLength 'This sets the distance from the end row far enough to stop
                                                                   'calculating a FORWARD looking average. Even though it is historical data,
                                                                   'it is working through the data in a forward looking manner,
                                                                   'from earliest to latest. so it needs to stop roughly 200 rows
                                                                   'before the end to make sure all the calculations contain at least
                                                                   '200 data points

    With .Cells(FirstRow, 5).Resize(MovingAverageLength) ' reference the first range to sum
        For CurrentRowOffset = 0 To LastRowOffset 'defines a For loop starting from zero to
                                                  'the row 200 data points before the end of the data

             Dma200current = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Offset(CurrentRowOffset))

            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value = YesterdaysOpen
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 3).Value = YesterdaysHigh
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 4).Value = YesterdaysLow
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 5).Value = YesterdaysClose

            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset, 2).Value = TodaysOpen
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset, 3).Value = TodaysHigh
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset, 4).Value = TodaysLow
            .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset, 5).Value = TodaysClose

            .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 5).Value = Dma200current

             DMASlopeCurrent = (Dma200current - Dma200Tminus1) / Dma200Tminus1

            .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 6).Value = DMASlopeCurrent

            Dma200Tminus1 = Dma200current


        Next
    End With
```

End With
`

Comment: `CurrentRowOffset` is your loop counter, not a Range property.  Drop the `.`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use `.CurrentRowOffset`, which in your code would be the equivalent of:

```
Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(FirstRow, 5).Resize(MovingAverageLength).CurrentRowOffset
```

`CurrentRowOffset` is not a property of the range you're resizing. It's a variable, presumably declared as a `Long`..?

Change your `For.. Next` loop to:

```
         Dma200current = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Offset(CurrentRowOffset))

        YesterdaysOpen = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value
        YesterdaysHigh = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 3).Value
        YesterdaysLow = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 4).Value
        YesterdaysClose = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 5).Value

        TodaysOpen = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset, 2).Value
        TodaysHigh = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset, 3).Value
        TodaysLow = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset, 4).Value
        TodaysClose = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset, 5).Value

        .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 5).Value = Dma200current

         DMASlopeCurrent = (Dma200current - Dma200Tminus1) / Dma200Tminus1

        .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 6).Value = DMASlopeCurrent

        Dma200Tminus1 = Dma200current
```

Comment: when using the above code VBA returns a RunTime error 1004 "Application defined or object defined error", which seems to be caused by incorrectly specified variables. 

YesterdaysOpen is defined as Double and it's calculating numbers so i thought that should be ok?

the other source of the problem which i guessed might be an issue was assigning a cell the value of a variable which was not defined (i realised YesterdaysOpen should be equal to the value in cells(curr....offset, 2). However even when i switch these around the error remains. I haven't set a default value, is that required?

Comment: Can you post the whole routine? Or at least include the declarations and where you're putting values into `YesterdaysOpen` etc?

Comment: `Sub Calculate200DMA()

'OHLC price variables for yesterday and today

Dim TodaysClose() As Double
Dim YesterdaysClose() As Double
Dim TodaysOpen() As Double
Dim YesterdaysOpen() As Double

Dim Dma200Tminus1 As Double
Dim Dma200current As Double
Dim SumLast200Days As Long
Dim CrossUpIntraday As Boolean
Dim CrossUpEndofday As Boolean

Dim ClosingPrice200Array() As Variant
Dim DMASlopeCurrent As Double
Dim DMASlopeTminus1 As Double`

'then in the With loop shown above i have the line:
`Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value = YesterdaysOpen`

Comment: Just checking.. are you trying to put the value of `YesterdaysOpen` into the cell, or are you trying to put the value of cell into `YesterdaysOpen`?

Comment: I'm trying to put the value of the cell into the variable yesterday's open. Once 8 or so variables have been assigned values from a range of cells, I want to do some comparison calculations (for example yesterday's open is lower than today's open) and based on the results assign a Boolean value to another variable or assign particular value calculated in the loop to another cell

Comment: Oh! To load the value of a cell into a variable, you start your statement with the variable. Eg. `YesterdaysOpen = .Cells(CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value` - I'll change my answer.